# How to create a new CouchDB User without Futon or Curl?

Tags: coldfusion, couchdb

I'm searching for a way to create a new CouchDB user without using Futon or Curl... just a straight http request.

One way I found (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456256/error-creating-user-in-couchdb-1-0) puts a JSON doc to "http://localhost:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:username" to create a user.

I have attempted the following:

```
<cfhttp url="http://127.0.0.1/_users/org.couchdb.user:xyz_company" port="5984" method="PUT" username="#variables.couch_username#" password="#variables.couch_password#">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
<cfhttpparam type='body' name='org.couchdb.user:xyz_company' value='{"roles":[],"name":"xyz_company","salt":"3B33BF09-26B9-D60A-8F469D01286E9590","id":"org.couchdb.user:xyz_company","password_sha":"096EA41A5A81EA1507F2C6F7EDC364C0B82694AC","type":"user"}'>
```

I keep receiving the following back from Couch:

**cfhttp.statuscode** = 405 Method Not Allowed
**cfhttp.filecontent** = Method Not Allowed; The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /_users/org.couchdb.user:xyz_company

Any thoughts or suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

I edited my code based on Marcello's suggestions. I still receive the same 405 Method Not Allowed error. Here is the code now:

```
<cfhttp url="http://127.0.0.1/_users/org.couchdb.user:xyz_company" port="5984" method="PUT" username="#variables.couch_username#" password="#variables.couch_password#"><cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json;charset=UTF-8"><cfhttpparam type='body' value='{"roles":[],"name":"xyz_company","salt":"3B33BF09-26B9-D60A-8F469D01286E9590","_id":"org.couchdb.user:xyz_company","password_sha":"096EA41A5A81EA1507F2C6F7EDC364C0B82694AC","type":"user"}'></cfhttp>
```

Any more suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Three notes: in `<cfhttpparam type='body'>` the `name` attribute is ignored. In the body, `"id"` should be `"_id"`. Content-Type should be `application/json;charset=UTF-8`.

Answer (score 1):

curl *is* a straight http request.  There are other ways to create such requests: you can craft them with your browser; you can use a different program (e.g. wget); or even write your own (e.g. in Python or in JavaScript with V8 or Rhino).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I need to create a user without Futon or Curl. I have tried with the code above with the stated error message. Any suggestions to correct the code above? Thank you.

Comment: If the curl program works, re-run it with `-v` and then run your CFHTTP with the equivalent option, see what makes the difference.  If Marcello is right and `name` attributes are ignored in body parameters, change the value to `org.couchdb.user:xyz_company={"roles":[],"name...` .

Comment: I tried out adding 'org.couchdb.user:xyz_company=' to the body with the same 405 error. Not sure how to add the '-v' option to my code?